# Given an Outer & inner box, determine where the inner box is positioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I'm struggling with a math problem and could use your help. I want to know the following:

- Is the inner box primarily on the left or right side?
- Is the inner box primarily positioned to the top or bottom of the outer box?

To figure this out I know the following:

- The height & width of the outer box, this is static at 200px
- The width of the inner box (var X)
- The inner box distance from the left of the outer box (var x2)
- the inner box distance from the top, (var y)

Any ideas oh how to determine if the inner box is primarily to the left or right.. top or bottom?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You don't know the height of the inner box?

Comment: Yes I do!.. lets call that xy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out the center of the inner box by averaging its left and right edges.  Then compare that to the outer box center to figure out its primary direction.

In the code below, I'm calling

> The height & width of the outer box, this is static at 200px

`outerH` and `outerW`

> The width of the inner box (var X)

`innerW`

(I'm assuming you know the height of the innerBox too and I'm calling that `innerH`)

> The inner box distance from the left of the outer box (var x2)

`leftPadding`

> the inner box distance from the top, (var y)

`topPadding`

```
function isPrimarilyLeft(outerW, innerW, leftPadding) {
  var outerCentroidX = outerW / 2;
  // center = (leftedge + right edge) / 2
  // leftedge = leftPadding
  // rightedge = leftpadding + innerWidth
  // center = (leftPadding + leftPadding + width) / 2
  //        = 2*leftPadding / 2 + width / 2 =
  var innerCentroidX = leftPadding + innerW / 2;
  return innerCentroidX < outerCentroidX;
}

function isPrimarilyTop(outerH, innerH, topPadding) {
  var outerCentroidY = outerH / 2;
  var innerCentroidY = topPadding + innerH / 2;
  return innerCentroidY < outerCentroidY;
}
```

Comment: What is outerW, innerW, leftPadding in this example?

Comment: Tried this first w isPrimarilyLeft and it's always returning true. The values for something that should have returned false were: (200, 121.5,54.5)

Comment: @AnApprentice, edited to make it clear how the parameter names correspond to the things you know.

Comment: @AnApprentice, if your inner box has width 121.5 and starts 54.5 pixels in, its center is at 115.25 which is right of the outer box's center so most of its area is right of the outer boxes center line.  In http://squarefree.com/shell/shell.html , `isPrimarilyLeft(200, 121.5, 54.5)` yields false.
false

Comment: wow wow, that did it for primarilyLeft. Can't thank you enough. really I cant

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain the basic thought process for one possible solution.

To calculate if it is "left" or not, you want to determine which distance is greater, the distance between the left of the inner box, to the outer edge or the right.

You already know the distance on the left.  To calculate the distance on the right you need to take the total outerWidth and subtract the width of the inner box and the distance from the left:

```
|-------------------------Outer Box----------------------------------|
|---left distance---|---------inner box--------|---right distance----|
```

Now if the left distance is larger than the right, it is "right", if they're equal, it is centered and if it is less it is "left".

The same goes for top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The box is primarily on the left: X < (200 - x2)/2

The box is primarily on the right: X > (200 - x2)/2

The box is primarily on the top: Y < (200 - y)/2 
(I suppose you can calculate the box's height - Y)

The box is primarily on the bottom: Y > (200 - y)/2

You should replace 200 by width/height constant.